Remove rows within a certain time period based on another column
I have a dataset with individuals who have attended certain clinics and I want to remove 184 codes that occur within 42 days (<= 42 days) of a test.
library(data.table)

date=c("2023-01-01", "2023-04-07", "2023-07-20",
       "2023-01-01", "2023-04-07", "2023-04-20", 
       "2023-01-01", "2023-04-07", "2023-04-20", 
       "2023-01-01", "2023-01-10", 
       "2023-01-01", 
       "2023-01-01", "2023-06-01",
       "2023-01-01", "2023-05-01", 
       "2023-01-01", "2023-01-10",
       "2023-01-01", "2023-01-10",
       "2023-01-01", "2023-01-07", "2023-05-20")
patient_id=c("A", "A", "A", 
             "A2", "A2", "A2", 
             "A3", "A3", "A3", 
             "B", "B", 
             "C", 
             "D", "D", 
             "D1", "D1", 
             "E", "E", 
             "F", "F",
             "G", "G", "G")
clinic_code=c("Axxx", "Axxx", "Axxx","A2xxxA", "A2xxxA", "A2xxxA","AxxxA", "AxxxA", "A6xxxA", "Bxxx", "Bxxx", "Cuhdq", "Dxxx", "Dxxx", "diuhwq", "diuhwq", "Exx", "Exx", "hddwq", "hddwq", "Gx", "Gx", "Gx")
test=c(1, 1, NA, 
       1, 1, NA, 
       1, 1, NA, 
       1, NA,
       1,
       1, NA,
       1, 1,
       NA, NA,
       NA, 1,
       NA, 1, 1)
code=c(152, 156, 184, 152, 156, 184, 152, 156, 184, 156, 184, 156, 152, 184, 152, 154, 184, 184, 184, 152, 184, 152, 154)
df=as.data.table(cbind(date, patient_id, clinic_code, test, code))  
df[, date := as.Date(date)] 

Some things to note:

It is only rows with code 184 that I want to de-duplicate
I want to remove 184 codes where they are within 6 weeks (<=42 days) of test==1 (either before or after) (see example patient_id A2, B, G)
I want to remove multiple 184 codes that are within 6 weeks of each other (see example patient_id E)
I want this de-duplication to occur based on the patient_id and clinic_code (so for example all rows for person A3 would be left in due to a different clinic_code being present)

Using that scheme it is the yellow rows that would be removed:


This may not be the most efficient code, but it serves the purpose and is very easy to understand:
library(data.table)

df[order(patient_id, date), 
     flag := ifelse(abs(difftime(shift(date), 
                                 date, 
                                 units = "days")) <= 42 &  
                    code == 184, 
                    TRUE, 
                    FALSE)][
                        flag == FALSE, 
                        c(1:5)]

What you're doing there:

You are sorting by patient and date, so the next call to shift makes sense.
You are creating a new column flag that is TRUE if both conditions are TRUE:

The number of dates between consecutive rows is less than 42. I use the abs to lump together the backward / forward cases.
The code of the line is 184.


We filter the data in the cases where flag == FALSE (those where the conditions weren't met), and return columns 1 to 5.

The obtained output is:
          date patient_id clinic_code   test   code
        <Date>     <char>      <char> <char> <char>
 1: 2023-01-01          A        Axxx      1    152
 2: 2023-04-07          A        Axxx      1    156
 3: 2023-07-20          A        Axxx   <NA>    184
 4: 2023-01-01         A2      A2xxxA      1    152
 5: 2023-04-07         A2      A2xxxA      1    156
 6: 2023-01-01          B        Bxxx      1    156
 7: 2023-01-01          C       Cuhdq      1    156
 8: 2023-01-01          D        Dxxx      1    152
 9: 2023-06-01          D        Dxxx   <NA>    184
10: 2023-01-01         D1      diuhwq      1    152
11: 2023-05-01         D1      diuhwq      1    154
12: 2023-01-01          E         Exx   <NA>    184
13: 2023-01-10          F       hddwq      1    152
14: 2023-01-07          G          Gx      1    152
15: 2023-05-20          G          Gx      1    154


Thanks for your help - although this code does not take account of the patient_id and clinic_code. The code needs to distinguish a unique person based on both of those identifiers.

I have edited the original post to reflect this
